# Custom NPM UI Library, Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have created a base NPM package that I will be loading all of my UI elements from the past couple of years. I created the package and uploaded it to NPM. However, when I install the package onto another project and try to use a button, I receive an error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'ui-library-lofidevelopment' in 'C:\Users\Scott Selke\Documents\Personal_projects\test\test\src'

I have tried messing around with webpack, thinking that might be the problem. I have also updated all dependencies to make sure there were no breaking errors. In my local setup, I am able to access the code no problem. However when installed from NPM the package does not work.

My test app with ui-library-lofidevelopment installed via npm:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Button } from 'ui-library-lofidevelopment';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
        <Button text={"fuck you this worked"} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ui-library-lofidevelopment",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/parcel src/docs/index.html",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "build:docs": "./node_modules/.bin/parcel build src/docs/index.js -d dist/docs/"
  },
  "author": "Scott Selke",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
// const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build/lib'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        library: '',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
               test: /\.scss$/,
               use: [
                   "style-loader",
                   "css-loader",
                   "sass-loader"
               ] 
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.scss', '.js', '.json', '.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.svg'],
    },
    plugins : [
        // new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        //     template: "./src/index.html",
        //     filename: "./index.html"
        // }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ]
}
```

I expected that the npm package would install and be available. However I received the error Module not found.

Comment: yes, it doesn't exists https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ui-library-lofidevelopment

Comment: @JuniusL. It may not show up on npm but if you install the package it shows in node_modules

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So my solution was this:

I had my webpack output set as

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build/lib'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        library: '',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
    },
```

and my main in package.json set to :

```
"main": "./dist/lib/index.js",
```

Hence the two did not line up.